# Is there a product of chain complex?

Tags: homology-cohomology

In the Cup_product article of Wikipedia:

> It is possible to view the cup product as induced from the following composition:
> $$C^\bullet(X)\times C^\bullet(X)\to C^\bullet(X\times X)\overset{\Delta^*}\to C^\bullet(X)$$

How is $C^\bullet(X)\times C^\bullet(X)$ defined? Is it just a typo for $C^\bullet(X)\otimes C^\bullet(X)$?

Comment: Yes for consistency and you might actually also want to put in the explicit $\operatorname{Tot}$ too just in case you also use $\otimes$ to get a double complex.

Comment: @user10354138 What is Tot and what did you mean?

Comment: [Total complex of a double complex](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/total+complex).